# Should coordinate transformations from J2000 to ITRF93 in quaternions be cyclic?

Tags: earth, jpl-horizons, coordinates, spice, quaternion

I used SPICE's [pxform](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/spicelib/pxform.html) at an interval of epochs to determine the transformation from J2000 (inertial) to ITRF93 (Earth body-fixed) frame. Then, I converted these rotation matrices to quaternions with SPICE's [m2q](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/spicelib/m2q.html) function. Lastly, I converted it to the alternative quaternion formulation where the real part is the last element.

I am looking at the result and I'm not sure that it's reasonable since there are a lot of cyclic fluctuations in the quaternion values. Previously, I have done transformations for J2000 to MOON_ME (moon body-fixed) frame and there was not these cycles in the same epoch interval. Is my result reasonable or do I need to rethink how I'm using SPICE for this to make sense?

The kernels I'm using are as follows:

```
KERNELS_TO_LOAD=(
    'KernelsMoon\PCK\pck00010.tpc',
    'KernelsMoon\PCK\moon_pa_de421_1900-2050.bpc',
    'KernelsMoon\PCK\earth_000101_200729_200507.bpc'
    'KernelsMoon\FK\moon_080317.tf'
    'KernelsMoon\SPK\de430.bsp'
    'KernelsMoon\LSK\naif0012.tls.pc'
    )
```

See the picture for how the first quaternion element undergoes periodic change over time:
[image: Quaternion element 1 (r*sin(phi)]

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking at the result and I'm not sure that it's reasonable since there are a lot of cyclic fluctuations in the quaternion values.

1689593 seconds is about 19.6 sidereal days. The graph shows 19 to 20 cycles -- just about what should be expected.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. And for the J2000 to MOON_ME frame conversion which I just looked now, there's a cycle as well but for about 27 days due to its rotation.